# How does JavaScript perform with multi-variable equations?

Tags: javascript, math, client-server

I'm writing a web app that will have several multi-variable equations being evaluated algebraically. The expressions themselves are nothing complex but I am expecting relatively long running times.

How does JS scale with doing math? Should I use Python to do the work on the server and then feed the data back to the client? I've never approached this sort of problem before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Being interpreted languages, both Javascript and Python are not the best choices for numerical calculations. However Python has a library called NumPy that can be used for high performance calculations, especially with arrays.

But if you feel more comfortable with Javascript, just build a prototype application and check if you really have a performance issue.